# intercepting/recording REST requests from a .net application

Tags: xml, http, rest

This is a two part question:

Question 1: I am writing a .NET REST client that will connect to and consume a REST service.  I would like to view the xml/json content of the REST requests and responses, regardless of what method I am using to make the calls (WebRequest, HttpClient, third party REST library).

I am currently using Wireshark to view the web traffic, but this is not the most effective way of viewing XML data.  There's got to be a better way out there.  I want to see nice-ly formatted xml/json, along with the http headers.   Is there a tool out there that can help?

Question 2: On a related note, are there any good .net libraries for consuming REST services? I've tried Hammock, but i'm not a fan. I'm looking for something that's well documented and easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question two, [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) is my go-to REST client.

Comment: Tahnks Joe. Just stumbled across RestSharp a few minutes actually. I'm liking what i see so far!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Joey. RestSharp was pretty useful, and is now my go to library for any REST related development in .net.

As for question 1: Since first posting this question, I've found that [PostMan Rest Client](http://www.getpostman.com/) is my absolute favorite. Postman is a Chrome plugin, and it's perfect for viewing raw REST request/response data during the pre-development testing phase.